# What is the best way to avoid repeated processing in generateMetadata function in Nextjs 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, meta-tags, next.js13

Remove duplicate handling of generateMetadata in Nextjs 13 (Using App Route)

Hello,

I'm having a problem with Nextjs 13's generateMetadata (Using App Router).

In page.js I get the slug from the URL and call the API to get the Article content:

```
export default async function ArticleDetail({ params }) {
     const url = config.API.HOST + 'article/' + params.slug;

     let res = await fetch(url,
         {
             method: "GET",
             next: {
                 revalidate: 100
             }
         }
     );
     var article = await res.json();
     article = article.data;

     ...

     return (
          ...
     )
}
```

In this ArticleDetail function I have some processing to get the html_title, html_description information (this information is also used for many other functions not just meta tags).

However, generateMetadata function runs independently of ArticleDetail and I don't know how to share data between them. Even using a global variable is not possible because generateMetadata finishes running first, so it can't get the data of ArticleDetail.

In [Nextjs's generateMetadata documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#returns) it says that fetch API commands will not be called again when duplicated. However, some of my processing in ArticleDetail is still being repeated in generateMetadata. This is unreasonable, adversely affecting the performance of the website.

I want to remove these duplicate handles. Is there any way to handle it?

Thanks !